# Swift Can I assign NSTextview as global that hasn't been created yet?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

**High level goal:** .
I'm trying to a make a text editor that can preview markdown files.

**Current status**:
Reading / Writing text files works fine.

**Problem:**
Adding / replacing a NSAttributedString to a textView is difficult.

Here's my code:
    import Cocoa
    import Down // md conversion lib

```
class Document: NSDocument {

    var string = ""
    var ref: NSTextView

    override init() {
        self.ref = NSTextView()
        super.init()
    }

    override class var autosavesInPlace: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func makeWindowControllers() {

        // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name("Main"), bundle: nil)
        // creates a new windowController on the fly when a new file is openend. That creates the new window...
        let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("Document Window Controller")) as! NSWindowController
        // the windowController contains a viewController
        self.addWindowController(windowController)

        // create reference to the textView inside the window we just created by opening the new file...
        let vc = windowController.contentViewController as! ViewController

        // THIS DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK
        self.ref = vc.textView            
    }

    override func data(ofType typeName: String) throws -> Data {
        // SAVE BACK TO FILE
        if let vc = self.windowControllers[0].contentViewController as? ViewController {
            return vc.textView.string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? Data()
        }
        else {
            return Data()
        }

    }

    override func read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String) throws {
        do {
            let s = try String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)                
            let down = Down(markdownString: s!)

            let fancyString = try! down.toAttributedString()
            //self.ref.insertText(fancyString, replacementRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: 10))
            self.ref.insertText("It might be working...", replacementRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: 10))

        }

    }

}
```

**Here's what I think is happening:** 
In order for this code to build, I need to assign a `NSTextView()` instance to `self.ref` in `init()`. I try to replace that textView with the textview that is created in `makeWindowControllers()`, but that doesn't appear to work.

I expect to see `It might be working...` in the new window, but instead just see a blank textView.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE** with solution

Thanks to @Willeke for raising this question. I assumed that `makeWindowControllers()` was called first. Turns out that `read()` is called and THEN `makeWindowControllers()` is called.

So I can assign `var fancyString:NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "hello")` as a class variable. Then set `fancyString` from the file contents in `read()` and update the textView in `makeWindowControllers` like so:

```
 // the proper way to insert an NSAttributedString into a textView
 vc.textView.insertText(fancyString, replacementRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: 10))
```

Comment: Which method is called first, `makeWindowControllers` or `read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String)`?

Comment: @Willeke Oh my goodness. That solved it. Thank you! I assumed the incorrect order. `read()` is called first! I'll update my question. If you suggest it, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeWindowControllers` is called after `read(from data: Data, ofType typeName: String)`. Assign the attributed string to a `Document` property and add the text to the text view in `makeWindowControllers`.

Details: [Message Flow in the Document Architecture, Opening a Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/AdvancedTopics/AdvancedTopics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH7-SW15) in [Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH1-SW1)